# How to install cloud foundry in home server

Tags: cloud, cloud-storage, rhel-7

I know this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596743/how-to-install-cloudfoundry-on-local-server) but found that was years before. Most of the instructions seems outdated. I want to install Cloud Foundry in my home/local server but would like to use it later for some research purposes. I know there may be alternatives but I really want to install cloud foundry in bosh. Most of the answers I found online says about installing on VM. I am very new to infrastructure architecture. I am trying to install on my Dell home server. I am thinking to install CF on a dedicated physical hard drive. I hope I am putting it all together in the right direction. I am using RHEL7. A help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

BOSH just by itself must run on a VM, or in a group of VMs (if you install bosh in a Cloud). If you want to run on a single server, you want to install "Bosh lite", for that you follow the appropriate instructions at https://bosh.io/docs/bosh-lite/